# Align ddots in nicematrix

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

So I am using the package nicematrix to write a matrix with unlimited entries, but the ddots on the middle and lower right are not aligned with each other. Is there a way to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
        C_{0m}C_{0m}&C_{0m}C_{1m} & \cdots \\
        C_{1m}C_{0m}&\ddots &\\
        \vdots& &\ddots\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.25} % <---                                       
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
C_{0m}C_{0m}& C_{0m}C_{1m} & \cdots \\
C_{1m}C_{0m}&   \ddots     & \\
\vdots      &              & \ddots
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sneaky but effective.  The key is making the cells essentially square.  One might complain that the dots in the middle are too high, not vertically aligned on the math axis, but trying to achieve that would only make the problem more difficult and the result more space-gobbling.  Well done.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, Good to have your comments!

Answer (score 3):

We should use `\Cdots`, `\Vdots`, `\Ddots` (unless you use the option `renew-dots`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[extra-margin=2mm]
C_{0m}C_{0m}  &C_{0m}C_{1m} & \Cdots \\
C_{1m}C_{0m}  &\Ddots      &        \\
\Vdots       &            & \hspace*{5mm}\\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

I have put `\hspace*{5mm}` in the last cell to have a non empty-cell (`nicematrix` does not like empty cells).

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t look particularly pretty to me. I especially don’t like the position of the diagonal dots or their end position.

Comment: @Gaussler: In fact, I think that such matrix is not good mathematical design. I think one should put at least the content of the four corners of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

To draw a nice dotted diagonal, *from the bottom center of cell to the top center of the other,* using `nicematrix` you need to do two things:

(1) Fill the cell with some content (invisible). I choose `\phantom{\cdots}` because you may want to show cdots after all.

(2) Use `\CodeAfter` to draw the dotted diagonal.

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}                                    
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
        C_{0m}C_{0m}& C_{0m}C_{1m} & \cdots \\
        C_{1m}C_{0m}& \phantom{\cdots}    &  \\
        \vdots      &             & \phantom{\cdots}\\
        \CodeAfter  % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
        \line{2-2}{3-3}
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```